# List table on preview/show page - Laravel Backpack

Tags: laravel-backpack

I have a list of products, I wish to included a list table (Sortable and searchable, just like the setupListOperation()) on the products preview/show page that contains all related orders. Is it possible to use the already existing operations to achieve this?

```
$this->crud->addClause('where', 'product_id', '=', $value);
```

What I am trying to achieve:
[image: What I am trying to achieve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mille, there are two user contributed packages to do that:

- https://github.com/sergioxdev/Laravel-Backpack-Relationship-CRUDs-inside-Show-Operation
- https://github.com/izica/relations-widgets-for-backpack

Good news on this regard is that we are already developing Backpack Components, that basically would allow you to re-use any Backpack Components (including the List table) anywhere you want, we should be slowly introducing them in the next minor versions of Backpack as non-breaking changes so people that want can start working with them (opt-in), but for now those two packages are what we have to offer (and thank the users who made them).

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! I am suprised my countless Google searches didn't bring these to my attention. Cheers!